# Brightness function will not work on a Dell 5521

Tags: power-management

I installed ubuntu 14.04LTS, as my previous version, this version still does not support brightness control function.

Is there any solution to this problem. Brightness bar decreases as well as increases on using of function but brightness itself does not.

Answer (score 0):

this command in terminal can change the brightness

sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

Where 1 is the brightness value u can change it from 0 to 9(or more)

this will get changed to default when u reboot, to permanently change the brightness open

sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

add the following line above 'exit 0' at the bottom of document

echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

save it

what happens is rc.local file loads at every boot and your brightness is set to 1 at every boot

if u want to remove this simply remove the echo line u added in rc.local file before 'exit 0'

i hope this helps you